# dropzone.js image upload acceptedMimeTypes

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using the dropzone.js plugin to add an image uploader to my application. I know this is probably a really basic question so apologies but what I want to do is limit the file extensions. This works for a single file extension,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log(file);
            if (file.type != "image/jpeg") {
                done("Error! Files of this type are not accepted");
            }
            else { done(); }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

So my question is how to add multiple file extensions, i.e. `image/jpeg`, `image/png`?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could add more extensions to your `if`, like so:

```
if (file.type != "image/jpeg" && file.type != "image/png") {
```

This will check if the file type is different from ALL of the types you specify. For a file to pass the check, it has to be different from image/jpeg AND image/png

**Update**

I would advise to look at [enyo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275873/1319187) since he is the author of Dropzone.

Answer (score 125):

I'm the author of Dropzone.

You should use the <strike>`acceptedMimeTypes`</strike> `acceptedFiles`. This behaves exactly the same as the `input` element's `accept` property. This way, even the fallback will work properly.

Valid `acceptedFiles` properties can look like this:

- `audio/*`
- `image/*`
- `image/jpeg,image/png`
- etc...

**EDIT**: in the latest versions of Dropzone this property is called `acceptedFiles` and it allows you to also define extensions. So this would work:

`"audio/*,image/*,.psd,.pdf"`

(For backwards compatibility `acceptedMimeTypes` will still work until the next major release)

Comment: It would be nice to have a similar property but the other way around. Block certain file types. For example, I am using this uploader in conjunction with PHP and I don't care what files they upload as long as they aren't PHP files. I can do this via PHP for now. I am really diggin this uploader you made though, great job.

Comment: @enyo This doesn't work when you drag and drop the file, it doesn't check the mime type

Comment: @enyo any infos about the drag & drop issue?

Comment: My experience has been that one must whitelist *both* the MIME-type and the extension, yet the documentation seems to say nothing of this requirement. I'm not sure whether this is because the MIME-type is not being detected correctly (or at all), or whether this requirement is intentional. I have seen others mention the same, which is why I knew how to address the issue when I encountered it.

Answer (score 36):

thanks enyo it worked ....awesome...just paste that line in dropjone.js->

```
uploadMultiple: true,  //upload multiple files
maxFilesize: 1,  //1 mb is here the max file upload size constraint
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
```

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles

> The default implementation of accept checks the file's mime type or  extension against this list. This is a comma separated list of mime types or file extensions. Eg.: `'image/*,application/pdf,.psd'`
>   If the Dropzone is clickable this option will be used as accept parameter on the hidden file input as well.

Answer (score 9):

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#profile_pictures',{
    acceptedFiles: "image/*", /*is this correct?*/
    init: function(){
        this.on("success", function(file, data) {
            /*..*/
            });
        } 
})
```

Comment: `acceptedFiles: "image/*",` is correct  - Replace `;` with `,`

Answer (score 1):

```
var dz = $("#FileUpload").dropzone({acceptedFiles: ".jpeg"})[0];
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21218663)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested (I can not comment on Enyo's post):
I have had problems with the application of the Dropzone options and after investigating I have noticed that the version of jQuery **jquery-3.2.1.min.js** that I was using was the cause of its malfunction